# How to concatenate string using HttpPostedFileBase in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I cannot find in the internet solutions how to concatenate or append an extra string in a file using HttpPostedFileBase.

For example I get this image file using HttpPostedFileBase :

```
hello.jpg
```

I want to concatenate a string:

```
hello00001.jpg
```

This will help me to prevent uploading images with same name in my server using ASP.NET MVC.

This is my code, so simple:

```
HttpPostedFileBase archivo = Request.Files["Image"];
if (archivo != null && archivo.ContentLength > 0)
   {
      var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), Path.GetFileName(archivo.FileName));
       archivo.SaveAs(path);

    }
```

I tried this:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), Path.GetFileName(archivo.FileName) + "00001");
```

But gives me this:

```
hello.jpg00001
```

also tried this:

```
archivo.SaveAs(path + "00001");
```

also gives me this:

```
hello.jpg00001
```

My issue looks so simple but I cant figure this out how to.

Comment: There are Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension and Path.GetExtension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this;

```
fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName); // hello
fileName+="00001";
fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName); // jpg

string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Uploads"), $"{fileName}{fileExtension}"); // ~/Uploads/hello00001.jpg


file.SaveAs(path);
```